# sqlite3 change to pg breaks app deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok, so I am following along in agile web development with rails 4th edition (rails 3.2+) and I am on chapter 16, which involves deployment. I followed along for the most part, but given that I want to use heroku, I decided to go ahead and try to deploy my app to heroku. following these instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 I went about deploying heroku. However, when I went to visit the app:

```
heroku open
```

I encountered this error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

So after running:

```
heroku logs
```

I realized that this is the error causing the issue:

```
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "carts" does not exist
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"carts"'::regclass
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-07-25T19:41:16+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

Now, while following the heroku instructions, I only modified two things in my gemfile. Firstly I changed:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to:

```
gem 'pg'
```

and I also added:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

at the top of the file. However, since the error sited "PG" I assumed the error arose b/c I changed the 'sqlite3' gem to 'pg.' I had developed the app with sqlite3, so I assume this is what caused the error. Trying to validate this, I changed 'pg' back to 'sqlite3' and ran "bundle install." However, upon doing so, I got this error:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
```

If I change back to 'pg' this error goes away. Please, somebody help a newbie out here. Why when I deployed my app to heroku did it not work and what is the meaning of the error I found in the 'heroku logs.' Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Because otherwise your database will not have tables, and thus will not have associations.

Comment: You sir, are amazing. Worked like a charm.

Comment: just out of curiosity, even though I changed my gem from 'sqlite3' to 'pg', I noticed that my database.yml file still has a sqlite3 database for the production environment. Shouldn't that have changed to pg?

Comment: not sure to be honest. My app has sqlite in production in the yml file too but seems to work fine with pg on heroku. I'm guessing based on intuition only that Heroku makes its own database.yml file when you push to it. Try changing it and see if anything breaks :)